# Can you say that $\mathbb{R}$ is Dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Denote the set of irrationals by $\mathbb{I}$.

We know that $\mathbb{R} = \mathbb{Q} \cup \mathbb{I}$, and we know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbb{I}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ as well. We know that between any two reals, we can find another real. Therefore, is it acceptable to say that the reals are dense in the reals?

Comment: yes, trivially, by definition of density. surely any superset of a dense set is dense.

Comment: Not only can I say that every topological space is dense in itself, it would even be true! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you say that $\mathbb{R}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Yes I can. Actually, every topological space $X$ is such that $X$ is dense in $X$, since:

- By definition, a set $Y\subseteq X$ is dense in $X$ if and only if $\mathrm{cl}(Y)=X$.
- For every subset $Y\subseteq X$, $Y\subseteq\mathrm{cl}(Y)$ and $\mathrm{cl}(Y)\subseteq X$.

Thus, no need to appeal to $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathrm{cl}(\mathbb Q)$ when $X=\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. We can.

It is the only dense closed subset of $\Bbb R$.

Recall that a set is dense if it meets every non-empty open set. Trivially, $\Bbb R$ satisfies this definition.

Comment: How hard is the uniqueness to prove?

Comment: Tim, not very much. You just need to know that dense + closed = everything.

Comment: D'oh. Time for me to go to bed... too tired.